# default date for gdatepicker

Tags: grails, datepicker

I am using the default gdatepicker in an application.  The end date is defaulted to the current date which works fine however I'm not sure of the syntax to set the begin date datepicker to July of the previous year.  Seems like this should be fairly easy but I have yet to find a good example.  Thanks!

Comment: The datepicker has no concept of a start/end date, just a date. Could you show some code and provide some more detail?

Comment: Sorry I should of clarified start and end date are just my field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the requirement is to set July of last year as a default date. If yes, then you can use something like below but I suggest to move the date logic to a controller and then populated a model to contain last year's July date:

```
<g:datePicker name="myDate" 
              default="${new java.util.GregorianCalendar(
                             new Date()[java.util.Calendar.YEAR]-1, 
                             java.util.Calendar.JULY, 
                             1, 1, 00, 00).time}"/>
```

Above sets the default date to July 1, 2013.

Groovy 2.2.0 comes with a useful utility method [**copyWith**](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#copyWith%28java.util.Map%29) on Date object, but this cannot be used in Grails right now as Grails uses previous versions of Groovy:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*

def today = new Date()
def lastYearJuly = today.copyWith(year: today[YEAR]-1, month: JULY)
```